# How do I make 'normal' sized components in Starling's Feather framework when working with FlashDevelop

Tags: flashdevelop, starling-framework

My current setup is as follows:

- FlashDevelop
- Starling (1.3 latest from Github, req. by Feathers)
- Feathers

I'm building the simple hello world example, as seen [here](http://wiki.starling-framework.org/feathers/getting-started) but the components are appearing extremely small (see image below).

I have also checked out the FAQ which describes the issue, but I can't seem to get the fix to work (as I'm not working within the AIR environment, I just want to publish to standard ol' SWF). See the second last question/answer [here](http://wiki.starling-framework.org/feathers/faq)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this somewhat hidden gem (by going through some examples):

```
DeviceCapabilities.dpi = 90*3;
```

This does the job - I have no idea why the right value seems to be my screen DPI multiplied by 3, but it's spot on .

Answer (score 0):

You can also just do:

```
DeviceCapabilities.dpi *= 3;
```

To magnify the already set DPI.

Answer (score 0):

This answer give me a clue, after I "magnified" DPI several times, and have no size inrease after x3. The trick is the Feather tutorials are a bit out of date, and probably lost a clue they are designed for **mobile**. And all the assets in the feathers.themes.**MetalWorksMobileTheme** are actually for mobile. So you should simply give a try for feathers.themes.AeonDesktopTheme, it works just fine out of the box.